# Kerberos net ads join doesn't respond

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to join Active Directory in Xubuntu 16.04 in a enterprise business enviroment so I'll change the name of my REALM by MY.EXAMPLE.CORP. My issue is: when I run

```
net ads join -U Administrator
```

it asks me the password for the AD administrator account, I put the password but it stills there, it doesn't give an error or success message. Just still there. The terminal just hanged in there

I tried the `kinit` and `klist` commands and the result is:

```
Tickect cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: Administrator@MY.EXAMPLE.CORP

Valid starting      Expires         Service principal
11/11/16 09:58:40   11/11/16 19:58:40   krbgt/MY.EXAMPLE.CORP@MY.EXAMPLE.CORP
    renew until   12/11/16 09:58:34
```

I've modified all the files as I've read. krb5.conf, smb.conf, nsswitch.conf

Comment: What's in your `krb5.conf`? Can you contact your domain controllers as configured in your `krb5.conf` from the host you're trying to join to the realm?  Do you see the Computer object get created on the AD server?  Can you create computer objects manually using your Administrator account?  Also, this may be a better question for ServerFault (http://serverfault.com/) than for Unix & Linux StackExchange (there is some overlap between the two sites).